# iOS 8 modal views incorrect orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

My application is configured to be Portrait only.
There are **only two** views which I want to auto rotate.
So in application delegate I've overrided the following function:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**All my views inherit one view in which I overrided the following functions:**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{    
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

This allows me to keep  all  views in a portrait orientation.

**In two views which I want to autorotate I  overrided the following methods:**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

And this also works as esxpected.

However view which is being shown modally is being opened in a device orientation - if I rotate the device to landscape orientation and open view modally it gets landscape layout even though it is inherits main view and does not override these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a reason and a solution for this.

My view is being managed by UINavigationController so there is a need to subclass it and override all of mentioned above functions exactly the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Your portrait views should autorotate but only to portrait orientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Please look in to my question. I did this. Also the problem is opposite. I do not want modal views to take any landscape orientation but they do.

Comment: In this case you should return YES in `shouldAutorotate`, but return only one orientation in supported and preferred

Comment: This is what I do. And this works for all views bot not for modal ones.

Comment: This is because in modal view controller you return `return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;`